# How to use an api that is mapped to a service in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, connection, azure-aks, kubernetes-service

I want to access my backend pods using an internal Kubernetes dns name. Instead of using http://somepodip:8080/get I want to use http://backend:8080/get to use my backend.

I am currently running my backend pods and have hooked them up to a service.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp-backend
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
```

This does assign my pods to the backend service. But when I try to use a frontend pod with http://backend/get , it does not find the resource.

Am I incorrectly configuring the service?

Comment: Your service seems to be ok, the issue could be possibly because your frontend is not server rendered, which means that your browser is trying to lookup for a name `backend`, in that case you cannot rely on kubernetes service name as your browser does not recognize it as a valid hostname.

Comment: are frontend and backend pods in the same namespace? `http://backend` should work if they are

Comment: Yes they are on the same namespace

Comment: Not clear about your question. Do you mean using the ingress and cannot access the backend service? What frontend you have used? Provide more details, the steps you have done.

Comment: I was not able to access my backend using services, I am using ingress now as recommend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service seems to be ok, the issue could be possibly because your frontend is not server rendered, which means that your browser is trying to lookup for a name `backend`, in that case you cannot rely on kubernetes service name as your browser does not recognize it as a valid hostname.

If you want to access externally by instead of ip, you want to use names, check how to setup a ingress entry https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress